# When I change my Laptop network one to another, Emulator isn't changing it without restarting it?

Tags: android, flutter, android-emulator

If I am connected to network which becomes weak after some time, and then I try to change my network, then emulator network is not changing without restarting it, which waste time

I have check many solution but didn't, How can I fix it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.